# How to report an error if an element is missing in the list of lists

Tags: python

suppose

```
list1 = [['a', (1, 1)], ['a', (1, 3)], ['a', (1, 4)], ['b', (2,1)], ['b', (2,2)], ['b',(2, 4)]]

list2 = [[(1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 4)]]
```

Now how could I report an error for list1 that ['b', (1, 2)] is missing or ['b', (2, 3)] is missing

Similarly for list2 there should be report error that (1, 2) or (2, 3) is missing

My intention is to report the error if for example something is missing in sequence like (1,1) then comes (1,2) followed by (1,3) if (1,2) is missing then error

Comment: what is the criteria for missing elements?

Comment: (1,1),(1,2),(1,3)... should come in sequence...if any one is missing then the error should be reported similarly for (2,1),(2,2),(2,3)..

Comment: So you just want to make sure that every subsequence with a given `val[0]` has a `val` for every `val[1]` between min `val[1]` and max `val[1]`?  What if `val[0]` is not contiguous?  Also, why are you not using a dict for `list1`?

Comment: Also, what are you supposed to do if you find a duplicate (ex `list2` contains 2 elements `(1, 2)`).

Comment: Is this homework?  If it is, then please tag it as such.  Thanks!

Comment: First, create the complete list with all elements, and then minus it from the target list; the resulting list is those elements that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dict instead of a list. But here's a solution using your structures. `s1` is a similar idea as the previous answer but *note the unnecessarily long list comprehension* to get the pattern you have in `list1`. And you require a specific for loop to check rather than the set "`-`" operator.

```
>>> s1 = [[x, (c, d)] for x in ['a', 'b']
...                   for c in range(1, 3)
...                   for d in range(1, 5)
...                   if x=='a' and c==1 or x=='b' and c==2]
>>> s1
[['a', (1, 1)], ['a', (1, 2)], ['a', (1, 3)], ['a', (1, 4)],
 ['b', (2, 1)], ['b', (2, 2)], ['b', (2, 3)], ['b', (2, 4)]]
>>>
>>> list1 = [['a', (1, 1)], ['a', (1, 3)], ['a', (1, 4)],
...          ['b', (2, 1)], ['b', (2, 2)], ['b', (2, 4)]]
>>> for thing in s1:
...     if thing not in list1:
...         print 'missing: ', thing
...         # or raise an error if you want
...         
missing:  ['a', (1, 2)]
missing:  ['b', (2, 3)]
```

Repeat the same for `list2`. Creating `s2` should be easier using the example for `s1` above.

Btw, the dict would look like this for `list1`:

```
dict1 = {'a': [(1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 4)], 'b': [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 4)]}
```

Then creating s1 is simplified a bit and but the comparison loop might get two lines longer.

---

To answer your question to **generalize**, then either **1.** knowing letters first or **2.** knowing numbers/number of letters?

**Knowing letters:**

```
>>> set_of_letters = ('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> s1 = [[x, (ord(x)-96, d)]
...       for x in set_of_letters
...       for d in range(1, 5)]
>>> s1
[['a', (1, 1)], ['a', (1, 2)], ['a', (1, 3)], ['a', (1, 4)],
 ['b', (2, 1)], ['b', (2, 2)], ['b', (2, 3)], ['b', (2, 4)],
 ['c', (3, 1)], ['c', (3, 2)], ['c', (3, 3)], ['c', (3, 4)]]
```

**Knowing numbers:**

```
>>> number_of_letters = 3
>>> s1 = [[chr(c+96), (c, d)]
...       for c in range(1, number_of_letters + 1)
...       for d in range(1, 5)]
>>> s1
[['a', (1, 1)], ['a', (1, 2)], ['a', (1, 3)], ['a', (1, 4)],
 ['b', (2, 1)], ['b', (2, 2)], ['b', (2, 3)], ['b', (2, 4)],
 ['c', (3, 1)], ['c', (3, 2)], ['c', (3, 3)], ['c', (3, 4)]]
```

Comment: what if I had c, d, e...that means my list would be  [['a', (1, 1)], ['a', (1, 3)], ['a', (1, 4)], ['b', (2,1)], ['b', (2,2)], ['b',(2, 4)],['c',(3,1)], ('c', (3,4)),['d', (4,1)], ['d', (4,2)] ,['d', (4,4)]]. I am looking for a more general solution to this problem

Comment: hint: `ord('a')-96 == 1`. So you're saying, in `[[x, (c, d)]` the `c` is always 1 for 'a', 2 for 'b', etc.?

Comment: I've added the "generalization" for creating `s1`. The checking loop with `for` remains the same.

Comment: I meant to say the sequence doesn't restrict itself to just a b or c...it could be d, e, f etc..each of 'a' , 'b' or 'c' or whatever  could have the sequence so that means we could have this appended to the list ['c', (3,1)], ['c', (3,3)] and after that ['d', (4, 1)], ['d',(4,2)], ['d', (4,4)] and so on...finally we have to report an error if ['d',(4,3)] or 'c',(3,2) is missing..

Comment: Then convert your `list1` to a dict as I mentioned originally in my post. Then it's easier to compare each letter 'key' having a 'set' to a fixed set. So instead of appending  your list, create your own function to take out the letters and add it to `dict1`, so that it looks like `dict1 = {'a': [(1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 4)], 'b': [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 4)]}`

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
missing = []
dict1 = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
dict2 = defaultdict(list)
for key, sublist in set1:
    dict1[key][sublist[0]].append(sublist[1])
for key, value in set2:
    dict2[key].append(value)
for key, subdict in sorted(dict1.iteritems()):
    for subkey, values in sorted(subdict.iteritems()):
        subkey_misses = []
        last_value = None
        for value in values:
            if last_value is not None and last_value + 1 != value:
                subkey_misses.extend(range(last_value + 1, value))
            last_value = value
        if subkey_misses:
            misses.append('%s.%d missing %s' % (key, subkey, subkey_misses))
for key, values in sorted(dict2.iteritems()):
    key_misses = []
    last_value = None
    for value in values:
        if last_value is not None and last_value + 1 != value:
            key_misses.append(range(last_value + 1), value))
        last_value = value
    if key_misses:
        misses.append('%d missing %s' % (key, key_misses))
print misses
```