# How to report an error if an item is missing in sequence in a list of lists

Tags: python

```
for i, e in enumerate(l1):
    if (e[0] == e[1]) and ((e[0], e[1]) not in l1):
        raise ValueError, '%s is missing' %(e[0], e[1])

    if i!=len(l1)-1:
        if e[0]==l1[i+1][0] and e[1]!=l1[i+1][1]-1:
            raise ValueError, '(%s,%s) is missing ' %(e[0], e[1]+1)
```

l1 = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 3)]

I am able to work for missing (1,2) and (2,2) but in the above case first it should look for (1,1) to report an error if it's not there however in the above code it goes undetected. Likewise it should traverse the whole list to check if any thing is missing. also what if I want (2,4) and its missing in l1. There should be a error been reported here as well

Comment: How does this differ from your previous question? ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763448/how-to-report-an-error-if-an-element-is-missing-in-the-list-of-lists )

Comment: its the same one and I am stuck on this one.

Comment: It is generally **REALLY** frowned upon to post the same question twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm ignoring your other question as you would simply need to check whether the front letters are the same.

EDIT: Apparently I missed some. New solution that is horribly inefficient and kind of ugly:

```
missing = []
num = {}
for i,e in enumerate(l1):
    if not e[0] in num:                # first number groups
        num[e[0]] = []                 # make a list of them (empty... for now)
        for z,q in enumerate(l1):      # for all of the numbers
            if q[0]==e[0]:             # that are in the first number group
                num[e[0]].append(q[1]) # append 
                                       # then start again with second number group

for i in num.keys():                            # for each number group
    for e in xrange(min(num[i]),max(num[i])+1): # from minimum to maximum, iterate
        if not e in num[i]:                     # if any number isn't there
            missing.append((i,e))               # make note

print missing # [(1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 2)]
```

Comment: The output doesn't show (2,4) which is missed in the list and (3,2) as well

Comment: sorry (3,2) is fine however (2,4) is missing in the output

Comment: also what if (1,1) or (2,1) is missing??

Comment: then hardcode it to start at line 11. It sounds like you know the length of these lists. Maybe if you told us what this DOES or is CHECKING we could help more.

Comment: I have just edited the question. Hope it makes u clear of my doubt

Comment: It's impossible to check if something is missing if you don't know it has to be there. I can check from 1,1 to 1,X and everything in between, but I can't check for (2,4) if I don't know it's supposed to be there because it only goes up to (2,3). In outlying cases such as this, you have to hardcode it as it can't be interpolated from your existing data set. Again, it sounds like you have an idea of what each data set should have. Just hardcode it as `for e in xrange(1,MAXVAL):` in my second block of code and it should provide functionality you want, even if you have to ignore a couple extras.

Comment: Granted, it's possible to gather (1,1) or (2,1) is missing, as this is the understood start of the dataset, but if it gets large, how should I know your last item should be (2,452) and not (2,453)? You have to tell it!

Answer (score 1):

In general terms:

```
from itertools import product

#`m` and `n` denote the upper limit to the domain of the first and second tuple elements.
complete_set = set(product(range(1, n), range(1, m)))

#`i` is whichever sublist you want to test. You get the idea.
test_set = set(l1[i])

missing_set = complete_set - test_set
```

*EDIT*

To check if a sequence is out of order:

```
sorted(sequence) == sequence
```

Comment: I am done with the edited part. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

```
l1=[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 5)]
for i,elem in enumerate(l1[:-1]):
    nxt = ((elem[0],elem[1]+1),(elem[0]+1,elem[1]))
    if l1[i+1] not in nxt:
       print "Error, something is missing should be one of:",list(nxt)
```

output:

```
Error, something is missing should be one of: [(1, 3), (2, 2)]
Error, something is missing should be one of: [(1, 5), (2, 4)]
Error, something is missing should be one of: [(2, 3), (3, 2)]
```

Comment: what if I have to detect the first occurence of an error so that when I correct it then it should detect the next error and so on. I hope u get my point